Adding a Checkable Star in place of a checkbox
I want to add a star in place of a checkbox that is yellow when checked and grey when unchecked. I can't figure it out for the life of me. I removed any of my original testing to get the base checkbox back. Any answers will be greatly appreciated!
      //styling for checkbox
.checkbox-container 
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

                  <!-- checkbox input --!>  
                     <div class="checkbox-container">
                            <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                id="IsFavorite_@item.ProjectIdNum" 
                                name="IsFavorite" 
                                value="true"
                                @(item.IsFavorite ? "checked" : "")
                                onchange="toggleCheckbox('@item.ProjectIdNum', this.checked)"
                                />
                        </div>


//Updates checkbox
function toggleCheckbox(projectIdNum, isChecked) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCheckbox", "PrevailSupport")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                projectIdNum: projectIdNum,
                isFavorite: isChecked
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
              
                $.notify({
                    message: r.message
                }, {
                    type: 'success',
                    timer: 4000
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
    }

I have tried the fa fa star symbol with css styling, but I have not been able to update the class for the star to change the color of it on click.

Please include your attempt to solve this problem (you say you "tried the fa fa star symbol with css styling", but did not show how you tried this).

I tried this by trying to remove and add the different css star classes to it on click, (yellow and grey), but it did not update correctly

Please post the code you tried, not a description of it.

Simples - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xxNXpqj

Thank you Paulie! I used the basic template of your code and got it working

Got it working with this:
css:
.star {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;   
color: gray;
font-size: 1rem;
cursor: pointer

}
    input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .star {
    color: yellow;
}

html:
<div class="star-container">
@{
    var labelID = "star_" + @item.ProjectIdNum;
    var spanID = "star_span_" + @item.ProjectIdNum;
}
<label for="@labelID">
    <input id="@labelID" type="checkbox" @(item.IsFavorite ? "checked" : "" ) onchange="toggleCheckbox('@item.ProjectIdNum', this.checked)" />
    <span class="star fa fa-star" id="@spanID"></span>
</label>


toggleCheckbox function did not change
